# Express "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError" in login middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm doing a RESTful API for a vuejs frontend with authentication and data saving by account.

I get this error when trying to log a user in.
Basically my frontend will send a request with a body containing a username and password.

Here's the log in middleware in express :

```
exports.post_LogIn = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
    .then(foundUser => {
      if (!foundUser) {
        console.log("no user");
        const error = new Error("No user with that username");
        error.statusCode = 400;
        error.tosend = "No user with that username";
        throw error;
      } else {
        return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, foundUser.password);
      }
    })
    .then(isEqual => {
      if (!isEqual) {
        console.log("wrong password");
        const error = new Error("Passwords don't match");
        error.statusCode = 400;
        error.tosend = "Passwords don't match";
        throw error;
      }
      console.log("logged in");
      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          username: foundUser.username
        },
        "secretpassword",
        { expiresIn: "24h" }
      );
      console.log(token);
      res.status(200).json({ username: foundUser.username });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(err.statusCode).json({ message: err.tosend });
    });
};
```

So basically when there's a problem with the credentials (either wrong username or password) I wanna send a response to the front end with a message saying what was wrong, and let the front end deal with it. 
This works just fine and as expected.

However when I send valid credentials, my console.log statement goes through, but the token and response part gives me this error

> (node:14515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError
>   [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined
>       at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:242:11)
>       at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:233:8)
>       at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:579:9)
>       at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:689:5)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/home/martin/dev/projets/trader-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:221:10)
>       at ServerResponse.json (/home/martin/dev/projets/trader-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
>       at /home/martin/dev/projets/trader-backend/controllers/UserController.js:97:34
>   (node:14515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:14515) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I tried commenting out the token part, or commenting the response and console logging the token, and I still get the same error.

However if I comment out the token and use res.send instead of res.json it seems to be working fine and my front end gets the response.

Any idea what might be causing this ? I'm kind of lost here

Comment: change your catch block to `res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json({ message: err.tosend || 'Internal Server Error' });`

Comment: Also `400` is not a correct status code for invalid credentials.